# Using SimpleExoPlayer with Room as offline cache

Tags: android, android-room, repository-pattern, offline-caching, exoplayer2.x

In my Android App project I want to let play videos from an offline cache when the user is not connected to a network. For that reason, I have built the app using the `Repository` pattern with the `Room` persistence library as recommended in the official Google codelabs.

The problem is that when the user is not connected to the internet, the videos are not playing although the video items are stored into the `Room` database table.

From my `Logcat` output, I can see the following error message:

```
2020-03-21 16:26:55.132 25186-25246/com.celik.abdullah.mylim6 E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
    com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: Unable to connect to http://192.***.**.***:8000/media/Videos/2020-03-16-12-26-49-268_CzixOFI.mp4
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:293)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:83)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:938)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:334)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:196)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:356)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:586)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.Platform.connectSocket(Platform.java:113)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectSocket(Connection.java:1455)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:1413)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:1700)
        at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:133)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:466)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:371)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:130)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:561)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:448)
        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:291)
```

I assume that `ExoPlayer` tries to make a connection to the webservice to get video via the corresponding URL. So, I think my `ExoPlayer` setup is somehow wrong.
My `ExoPlayer` setup is this:

```
playerView.player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
        playerView.context,
        DefaultTrackSelector())
        .apply {
            prepare(
                ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab"))
                    .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoString)), true, false)
            playWhenReady = true
        }
```

The `videoString` (to which ExoPlayer is trying to connect to) is the URL of a particular video item stored into `Room`. How can I refactor this so that `ExoPlayer` can use the cached video ? Is that possible ?

For sake of completeness, here is the `Video.kt` entity class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
@Entity(tableName = "video_table")
data class Video(
    @PrimaryKey
    @Json(name = "id")
    val videoId: Long,
    val title: String?,
    val text:String?,
    val video: String?,    // <--- that string is hold by videoString variable u have seen above
)
```

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but it looks like you just save an url to you video (stored somewhere in web) in your database. This case it won't work without network connection. 
In this case good approach is:

1 -  Save you video locally on your devise, for this you may use this library: https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/PRDownloader

2 - Save an entity of your loaded video to data base, but use a path to your local saved file as an url (video field)

3 - After fetchind data from data base use your local file path as videoString field in this code snippet:

```
 .apply {
        prepare(
            ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer-codelab"))
                .createMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoString)), true, false)
```